# How to identify the creator of the temporary table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, tempdb

On my server many users performing complex queries using tempdb. Sometimes a failed specifying boundary values ​​obtained are very large tables.

So I want to know who created **this** temporary table.

When I do:

```
select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where xtype = 'U' order by name
```

I get the names of the tables like this:

```
# tablename__________000000004EB1
```

How to determine the SPID user who created this table.

Comment: Hey @Arty, I've blogged about this too (though the second half of the blog post is only really useful for SQL Server 2012+): http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/dude-who-owns-that-temp-table

Comment: Thanks to @AaronBertrand for pointing out the existing response for the link to the blog.
Am surprised at how curved solution exists for this problem.